# TYPO3 security - IPmaskList and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using :

TYPO3 6.2

I want to add more security and restrict access to our website backend only to our IP range. Problem : I believe my company use a proxy and :

```
getenv:HTTP_HOST -> the same for everyone
```

But if I display in typoscript :

```
getenv:HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR -> then the real IP appears !
```

But the parameter [BE][IPmaskList] only cares about the HTTP_HOST, not the FORWARDED FOR. How to solve my issue ?

---

I also tried with .htaccess in the /typo3/ folder, but it doesn't work :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR} !^10$
    RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mycompany.com [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

(btw mod_rewrite is working fine, I use it in the parent htaccess for url rewriting). My goal is to deny backend from all except if HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR begins with 10.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

I would restrict it with a htaccess file. However if you care about security you should consider an update to latest version 8.7 as 6.2 is already end of life! You can also buy an extended support from the typo3 GmbH at typo3.com

Comment: Hello Georg and thank you for the answer. I tried your solution but nothing happends... I have edited my first post with the htaccess code.

Comment: Georg, I still have my issue. When you speak about htaccess restriction, you mean the "/typo3/" folder ? May it generates some errors with sysext and other stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

according to:
https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/TYPO3_6-2/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/FrontendBackendUserAuthentication.php#L187

and:
https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/TYPO3_6-2/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php#L3468

IPmaskList has nothing to do with HTTP_HOST.

Maybe your TYPO3 is running behind a reverse proxy,
then you need to set "reverseProxyIP" and "reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue" properly.